# Python: sum between a range

Tags: python

I have done the range list but I can't manage to sum up the `range(m,n)`. Where should I change in my code?

```py
def dk():
    nums = list(range(1,100+1))
    n=len(nums)
    for k in range (n):
        if (k+1)%4 == 3 or (k+1)%4==0:
            nums[k]= -nums[k]            
    return nums


def sumrangelist(m, n):
    sum_range = 0
    for i in range (m, n+1 , 1):
        sum_range =[dk()]
    return sum_range
    
m,n = map(int, input().split())

print(sumrangelist(m,n))
```

when I print the result is like:

```
[1, 2, -3, -4, 5, 6, -7, -8, 9, 10, -11, -12, 13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, -19, -20, 21, 22, -23, -24, 25, 26, -27, -28, 29, 30, -31, -32, 33, 34, -35, -36, 37, 38, -39, -40, 41, 42, -43, -44, 45, 46, -47, -48, 49, 50, -51, -52, 53, 54, -55, -56, 57, 58, -59, -60, 61, 62, -63, -64, 65, 66, -67, -68, 69, 70, -71, -72, 73, 74, -75, -76, 77, 78, -79, -80, 81, 82, -83, -84, 85, 86, -87, -88, 89, 90, -91, -92, 93, 94, -95, -96, 97, 98, -99, -100]
```

Comment: This is doing mysterious things for mysterious purposes. There is no way to know what you want here.

Comment: I am sorry ,I just want to know how to sum the range between the sumrangelist(the list mentioned below)

Comment: does `sum(dk[m:n+1])` perhaps do what you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I mean. Sorry for one more question, if I added sum(dk[m:n+1]), does the def sumrangelist(m, n): part still need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From discussion in comments, it seems like you can achieve what you want in inline code using

```
sum(dk[m:n+1])
```

but if you want to retain the function as-is, it can just be:

```
def sumrangelist(m, n):
    return sum(dk[m:n+1])
```

or perhaps better giving it the list to sum over:

```
def sumrangelist(values, m, n):
    return sum(values[m:n+1])
```

although as usual I *strongly* recommend using better names that refer to intent rather than names of structures.